# Concrete examples of $\sharp P_1$ complete problems? Self avoiding walks?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity

The only examples of $\sharp P_1$ complete problems I've seen are fairly abstract : e.g. here https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/enumerate.pdf

Valiant proves that there exists a $\sharp P_1$ complete sub-pattern matching type-problem, but he doesn't give it explicitly.

I know it was conjectured ( for example, it's mentioned here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750300080X ) that the number of self avoiding walks of length $n$ might be a $\sharp P_1$ complete problem. Has there been any progress on this problem? Or are there similar counting problems (some explicit combinatorial family) which have been shown to be $\sharp P_1$ complete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone with a long time interest in this complexity class, I don't believe there has been any significant work on $\#P_1$ since. (I was a Ph.D. student of Mitsu Ogihara, the second author of the paper you cite, and actually raised - in informal discussions with Mitsu - the open question you cite; of course, all the actual **results** on this problem are due to Mitsu and his coauthors only, I did not contribute to any of them)

What **is** known is that $\#P_1$ is a rather weak class: whereas (by Toda's theorem) $\#P$ is hard for the polynomial hierarchy, the assumption $\#P_1 = FP$ [has substantially weaker implications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9809002.pdf) (P=BPP). This is another result due to Mitsu.

There are [interesting complexity questions in enumerative combinatorics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06636.pdf). But (naturally as it may be) no connection  seems to have been made yet to the class $\#P_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's great to hear from someone who was there. Those references look very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another $\mathsf{\#P_1}$-complete problem from logic that you might find interesting:

Paul Beame, Guy Van den Broeck, Eric Gribkoff, Dan Suciu:
Symmetric Weighted First-Order Model Counting. PODS 2015: 313-328
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1505.pdf